# Electronic Yichud

Tags: yichud-seclusion

Can the concept of Yichud be extrapolated to include electronic Yichud?

By Electronic Yichud, I mean a man having a text message conversation (over WhatsApp) with a lady with whom he would be forbidden to have Yichud in real life.

This above mentioned form of communication does seem to be have some sort of privacy since no one can hear their conversation.

Comment: A man and woman can whisper to each other in broad daylight too without any prohibition of yichud

Comment: Is it Different than sending letters?

Comment: This would be like speaking over the phone which is also private. Yichud is specifically meant to be physical contact.

Comment: A better question is video chatting

Answer (score 1):

The prohibition of yichud is to prevent any physical things from happening, so there would be no digital yichud. Yichud is strictly physical.
The mishnah in avos does say to limit interactions with women, but this is not the prohibition of yichud, even if it has the same type of reasoning behind it.

Comment: "The prohibition of yichud is to prevent any physical things from happening" how do you know

Comment: @robev The gemara makes it very clear.

Comment: If you cite examples it would validate your answer